# Why is the add user or group button not available on the group policy editor for Remote Desktop Services Properties?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server, and I'm trying to give a domain user who is NOT domain admin the rights to login to this box via RDC.  I'm logged in as a domain admin.  Here's where I am:

[image]

When I double-click the Policy on the right pane, here is what I see:

[image: I blacked-out the existing accounts, but a couple were shown here - both are domain admin accounts]

As you can see, I can't add a user to this policy.  Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: If this is a domain environment - Has this group policy been defined already on the dc?

Comment: Also I think they account you use to edit local group policies has to be the local administrator, I don't know if domain admin will work - may need to be enterprise admin (i think)

Comment: It is a domain environment.  That may be defined on the domain controller, but not sure where to look for it.

Comment: On the dc go to administrative tools -> group policy management. I don't know how friendly your policy object names are, I normally limit custom settings to a few changes with an appropriate name - check under the default domain policy - click the settings tab and expand the report, see if you notice anything

Comment: you can check what group policy objects are being applied to the server by opening a command prompt and type gpresult /r too so you can narrow your search

Comment: actually sorry gpresult /r /v /z >c:\policy.txt   that will give you the policies and settings applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon for that policy indicates it's being controlled by a domain policy. Note how its icon is the two servers with the little script/document.

That means you need to either

- Create another domain-level GPO that only applies to the computer in question. You can do that by changing the computer's OU and putting the policy there. Also, you can change the security filtering on the new GPO so that it only applies to the computer in question, and set the GPO ordering such that the new GPO applies after the current GPO.

**OR**

- Prevent the computer in question from applying the domain-level GPO that is in effect now, and then set local GPO. You can change the permissions on the domain-level GPO such that the given computer is not allowed to apply it.

Comment: I wish I knew enough to understand all of that.  : -)  I get the basics, and I do have access to our domain controller box.  Is there a way I can add the user in question at the domain controller, as a domain-level setting?  I know this is a secondary question, but definitely related.

Comment: I wouldn't do it at a domain level setting unless you want that user to have rd access to all computers in the domain

Comment: I agree with Jeff.

Comment: @Ducain Since you blacked it out I can't tell if this applies to your situation, but by default that security policy includes the local group Remote Desktop Users. If you add the user account to that local group, it will also inherit the ability to log in through RDP. That way you can avoid creating group policies for individual machines.

Comment: @StephenJennings - the issue was I had this policy defined at the domain controller.  Thanks for the further input.